# Azure Active Directory B2C registration

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Can I create a registration form in my application and connect this form to AAD B2C? I develop in C #, React.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will need back-end logic via Graph API to talk to B2C as it requires permissions to do such things.

Comment: You should be able to add a reference to the other project.  Then add "using" statement at top of module.  Then create new instance of the class for the form (new myClass).

Answer (score 0):

You can choose between several OAuth 2.0 flows inside B2C that feats your needs. I recommend you to create an [Authcode Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow) inside B2C to render your signIn SignUp form.
You can start learning how to do it with the custom policies starter pack [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack)

Use in your browser this URL to start working with authentication form over B2C to get an access code then call with a POST to the token endpoint:

```
https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob
&response_mode=query
&scope=90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6%20offline_access
&state=arbitrary_data_you_can_receive_in_the_response
&code_challenge=YTFjNjI1OWYzMzA3MTI4ZDY2Njg5M2RkNmVjNDE5YmEyZGRhOGYyM2IzNjdmZWFhMTQ1ODg3NDcxY2Nl
&code_challenge_method=S256
```